# How can I stop my fragment from being destroyed?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a navigation view with some items in it, and when one item is pressed it will go to that fragment. For example, if you press the "Home" item, on the drawer, it will bring up the home fragment.

```
        navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.home_id:
                    HomeFragment homeFragment = (HomeFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("Home");
                    if (homeFragment == null)
                        homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.Main, homeFragment, "Home");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;

                case R.id.chat_id:
                    ChatFragment chatFragment = (ChatFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("Chat");
                    if (chatFragment == null)
                        chatFragment = new ChatFragment();
                    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.Main, chatFragment, "Chat");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Chat");
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
```

So what I think is happening is that when I am using the `replace()` method, it is destroying the chat fragment. What if I have data on the chat fragment, and I want to make sure the data does not go away when I change fragments.

In the `ChatFragment` class I have put this override method:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    Log.d("CHATFRAG", "onSaveInstanceState: been called ");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("textView",textView.getText().toString());
    //Save the fragment's state here
}
```

Now when I switch between fragments in my app, this method does not get called, which means the fragment is being destroyed.

Is there an alternative way where I can swap the current fragment that is on screen, with the desired fragment(without destroying both)?
I will be having more fragments (up to ten), is there an optimised solution that will not require duplicate code?

Comment: if you replace a fragment the one that gets replaced gets destroyed, that is the lifecycle of a fragment. if you have data you dont want to lose you should store that data somewhere on the device

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you are replacing fragment with other, so first one will get distroyed. If you dont want it to destroy you need to `add` it instead of `replace`

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.Main, homeFragment, "Home");
```

Comment: If I add this fragment, what happens with the fragment that is currently on?

Comment: it will gone in background.

Comment: so theortically the application will be stacking the fragments? One on top of another, like a layer of cake? Is this optimal for an android application?

Comment: yes it will be stacking the fragment, when you are again loading chat/home fragment you need to check it in stack, whether its available or not

Answer (score 3):

You can create your fragments in advance, for instance in your activity's `onCreate()` method:

```
private HomeFragment homeFragment;
private ChatFragment chatFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

    homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    chatFragment = new ChatFragment();
}
```

Then in your navigation code:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.home_id:
            if (homeFragment == null)
                homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.Main, homeFragment, "Home");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
            item.setChecked(true);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            break;

        case R.id.chat_id:
            if (chatFragment == null)
                chatFragment = new ChatFragment();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.Main, chatFragment, "Chat");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Chat");
            item.setChecked(true);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: "if you replace a fragment the one that gets replaced gets destroyed, that is the lifecycle of a fragment. if you have data you dont want to lose you should store that data somewhere on the device " tyczj

Comment: Sorry, so as tvcj, said using the replace method will destroy that instance, so the fragment will always be null, and will have to instantiate every time I change screens?

Comment: @Moynul Yes, that is true if you don't keep a reference to your fragment objects. In my example, you have them stored nicely in your activity and you can swap them around as you wish. They won't get destroyed completely until you leave the activity.

Comment: so keeping a global reference within the main activity will ensure the `onSaveInstanceState` to be called every time the `replace` method is called? I will test this solution.

Comment: @Moynul It won't call the `onSaveInstanceState`, as it doesn't need to. That method is for storing the instance state for a tad different use case. If you want to use that, you have to call `fragment.setRetainInstance(true)`.

Comment: so it appears that I've globally stored the fragments. But when I add something dynamically to the fragment, and then switch fragments, the object that has been added dynamically disappears.

Comment: @Moynul That sounds like a whole different problem. I can't really say what's going on there without seeing the code, I'm afraid.

Comment: I understand what's happening, so the 'replace' and 'add' method calls the 'onDestroy' method. In order to stop the fragments being destroyed, I need to either use the attatch, and detatch method? Do you know if this stops the fragments life cycle from being destroyed?

Answer (score 1):

Although I think Ravi Rupareliya's answer is the best choice (using `.add`), I'll share another way I think might work.

You can add two `FrameLayout` on top of each other, `.add` a `Fragment` into both, and then alternate their visibility.

Comment: yes, I agree, Ravi does have the best answer, practically, I thumbed up + @manbreak for the aftercare, and clear replies to my questions. So I add the fragments to the same layout. when I switch screens, I use the `isAdded()` method from the `Fragment` object. if It is, then make the other fragments invisible by using `hide()` on the `FragmentTranction` object. it's these two methods that where the key to ensure the `Fragment` objects were not deleted. If you have ever coded in `Unreal4` or `Unity3D` the same concept is used, to show and hide screens. Thanks for input.